# Swift NumberFormatter is giving compiler errors

Tags: xcode, swiftui

I am trying to use the NumberFormatter in a SwiftUI view but I am getting compiler errors. Here's my code:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct AccountCard: View {
    var netWorth: NetWorth
    
    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.numberStyle = .currency
    let investmentTotalString = formatter.string(for: netWorth.investmentTotal)
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(netWorth.name)
            Text(String(format: "%.2f", netWorth.investmentTotal))
            Text(String(format: "%.2f", netWorth.cashBalance))
        }
    }
}

struct AccountCard_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        AccountCard(netWorth: netWorths[0])
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Here's XCode showing the errors:

[image]

Comment: you cannot have statements like this `formatter.numberStyle = .currency` inside a view setup. Read-up on what you can and cannot do in particular places in views. In your case, declare the `formatter` where you have it, then in a `.onAppear` specify it. Similarly for `investmentTotalString`

Comment: Even if you could be do what you wanted, that would be very bad idea to create an instance of NumberFormatter in each body compute, try to use a class and do this kind of stuff inside that class, or define an instance in top level and use it with a function inside a view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't format strings ourselves anymore, we let SwiftUI do it for us. The reason for this is so it can update the labels on screen if the user changes their region settings. With UIKit most of us never bothered to listen to the locale changed notification to do it.

We can simply tell SwiftUI what format we'd like:

```
struct AccountCard: View {
    let netWorth: NetWorth
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(netWorth.name)
            Text(netWorth.investmentTotal, format: .currency(code: "USD"))
            Text(netWorth.cashBalance, format: .currency(code: "USD"))
        }
    }
}
```

Or we can pass a formatter object in to the string interpolation:

```
let currencyFormatter: NumberFormatter = {
    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.numberStyle = .currency
    return formatter
}()

struct AccountCard: View {
    let netWorth: NetWorth
    
    var body: some View {
      VStack {
          Text(netWorth.name)
          Text("$\(netWorth.investmentTotal, formatter: currencyFormatter)")
          Text("$\(netWorth.cashBalance, formatter: currencyFormatter)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Worth noting is that the first example works only iOS 15+/macOS 12+

Answer (score 1):

SwiftUI does not allow statements in its setup such as `formatter.numberStyle = .currency`. There are places
in a view, such `init(),` or `.onAppear{}` for example, and of course any custom functions,
where such statements are allowed.

To achieve what you want you could try something like this:

```
struct AccountCard: View {
    var netWorth: NetWorth
    
    let formatter: NumberFormatter = {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .currency
        return formatter
    }()
    
    @State var investmentTotalString: String?
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(netWorth.name)
            Text(String(format: "%.2f", netWorth.investmentTotal))
            Text(String(format: "%.2f", netWorth.cashBalance))
        }
        .onAppear {
            investmentTotalString = formatter.string(for: netWorth.investmentTotal)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Building on what workingdog wrote, creating `NumberFormatter` is an expensive operation, You should therefore make it e.g. static so it wouldn’t have to be recreated all the time. It’s also questionable whether you need State, you can always declare it as only var with getter.

```
struct AccountCard: View {
    var netWorth: NetWorth
    
    static let formatter: NumberFormatter = {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .currency
        return formatter
    }()
    
    var investmentTotalString: String {
         AccountCard.formatter.string(for: netWorth.investmentTotal)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(netWorth.name)
            Text(String(format: "%.2f", netWorth.investmentTotal))
            Text(String(format: "%.2f", netWorth.cashBalance))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I disagree, `..creating NumberFormatter is an expensive operation...`, this is not true.
`NumberFormatter` takes 128 bytes, you could have 10 thousands of these and still be cruising.

Comment: I actually haven't tested NumberFormatter myself, it seems to be better than I thought (at least compared to e.g. DateFormatter). But still, given how often the view will reload itself, it seems to me that everything that would be recreated so often should be static.

Comment: Just to be clear, I meant I haven't tested how expensive is creating the NumberFormatter

Comment: don't get me wrong, there is nothing wrong with the static.

Comment: @workingdog the problem is NumberFormatter is an object so it is stored on the heap. It is expensive for SwiftUI to create and destroy an object on the heap every time the View struct is created in the stack.

Comment: any supporting evidence of this. Is creating 128 bytes on the heap expensive?

Comment: Heap by design is slower than stack. The question is whether the view wouldn’t be created on heap as well (if it e.g. uses some object as a variable). You can see supporting evidence in UITableView and its dequeueReusableCell - it makes sense because creating it again is more expensive than reuse.